# create a connection_handler with pthreads in c (Linux/Windows)

Tags: c, pthreads

Ii try to write a programm that should work on windows and linux. It uses a server that handles data so i setup it using #def instructions until i came to multithreding. I searched a little bit and think, pthread should work fine out of the box (windows & linux).

I have an echo function that receives and sends data from and to the socket.

```
static void echo(int client_socket) { /* or SOCKET client_socket */
    char echo_buffer[RCVBUFSIZE];
    int recv_size;
    recv_size = recv(client_socket, echo_buffer, RCVBUFSIZE,0);
    echo_buffer[recv_size] = '\0';
}
```

to handle a client i have an endless loop that accept() the connection and pass it to echo function.

```
/* sock = int | SOCKET */
sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
memset( &server, 0, sizeof (server));
bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof( server));
listen(sock, 5);

for (;;) {
    len = sizeof(client);
    fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &len);
    echo( fd );
```

so i tried to replace the echo function with a pthread

```
    len = sizeof(client);
    fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &len);
    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL , echo, (void*) &client);
```

I also have tried to change the 4th parameter of pthread_create to pass it directly but cant figure out how to use them in my case.

Comment: Please reduce your task: Is it the networking, the multithreading or running on two platforms that's giving you problems?

Comment: 'echo( fd );' OK, fine.  Then, when you try to use pthread_create, you pass '(void*) &client' as the last argument. Why did you change from 'fd'?  mallocate a struct, copy fd and any other data bound to the client, into it and pass its address as the 'void*' last pthread_create argument.  Don't forget to free() the struct in the handler thread just before it exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a function that `pthread_create` can accept and you need to invoke it properly. Here's one way:

```
void* wrapper (void* fd)
{
    echo((int) fd);
    return NULL;
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL , wrapper, (void*) fd);
```

You should fix your `echo` function to correctly handle a return from `read` of zero or negative one.